# Sharing and Updating data with series of unrelated RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a series of computations that I distribute where all of the computations rely on data that is represented in Map. The thing is that on each step the Map should be also updated.

First the data sets, the RDD series is:

```
Iterable[Long, RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, String), Int])]]
```

Where the first Long is a signature of the RDD, the (String, String) Tuple is the key for the Map that is needed on all the nodes:

```
Map[(String, String), Double]
```

On each step the computation needs the double value and in turn updates the double value using the Int value.

I know that accumulators are write-only and cannot be used in my case for both reading and writing (I did try to read the data using `localValue` which didn't work).

The thing is in my case since each RDD is processed in turn, I was wondering if there still a hack that will be able to help me use the accumulators. Currently I wrote the following accumulator:

```
val accMap = sc.accumulableCollection(scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[(String, String), Double]())
```

And I am wondering if calling `accMap.value` after each calculation of a RDD data and distributing the map using broadcast variable is the best thing I can get? my problem is that the map is **REALLY BIG** so it is not quite feasible and if its the case the algorithm should be rethought.

basically my question is for the problem I described above is the best thing I can do is *on each consecutive RDD*: use accumulator Map for accumulating the score and collecting it using `value` function on each iteration just to broadcast it again using broadcast variable?

EDIT: Adding all the RDDs to a single RDD isn't feasible for me since the datasets are REALLY huge. this is the reason I tried to divide it into several unrelated RDD's.

Comment: @LostInOverflow I ment that each RDD is processed in turn (of course the calculations for each RDD are distributed) it kinda forms a serial manner of calculations per RDD. I changed the description in question to make it clearer

Comment: It's a little bit of an overhead, but you can maybe store the dataset using `sc.saveAsTextFile` everytime afer an update, and read it before dealing with it in the next `RDD`. Other than that, don't have any out standing idea.